# get sum() of column function using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

i'm trying to sum up the quantities in my stock column from mysqldb.

Current code is below. In sql the code looks like this

```sql
SELECT SUM(InStockSupplyQuantity) AS sum_stock FROM mwsinventory;
```

I haven't been able to get the result I need using sqlalchemy.

models.py

```py
class Item(Base):
__tablename__ = "mwsinventory"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    TotalSupplyQuantity = Column(Integer)
    InStockSupplyQuantity = Column(Integer)
    ASIN = Column(String, unique=True)
    SellerSKU = Column(String)
```

crud.py

```py
def get_item_stock_sum(db: Session, limit: int = 100) db.query(func.sum(models.Item.InStockSupplyQuantity).filter(models.Item.InStockSupplyQuantity > 0)).limit(limit).all()
```

main.py

```py
@app.get("/api/FBA/stock_sum", response_model=schemas.Item) 
async def read_items(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    db_item = crud.get_item_stock_sum(db)
    return db_item
```

error response:

```
raise ValidationError(errors, field.type_) pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 5 validation errors for 
Item response -> id   field required (type=value_error.missing) 
response -> TotalSupplyQuantity   field required (type=value_error.missing) 
response -> InStockSupplyQuantity   field required (type=value_error.missing) 
response -> ASIN   field required (type=value_error.missing) 
response -> SellerSKU   field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

Comment: I have fixed your code blocks, please fix the function in `crud.py` as its syntax is not correct and it returns nothing.

Comment: The error is about you saying that you're returning an `Item` - not a sum. The pydantic error says that it can't find the expected fields in the value you're returning (which is a row with just the sum), but you're saying it should be something conforming to the definition of `Item`; it's a FastAPI error, not a SQLAlchemy issue - the first step would be to see what you're getting back from your `get_item_stock_sum`, adjust what you're returning from your controller  and then adjust the response model to match what you want to return.